# Parse String value into AnyContent Value

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

I have String value

```
val a: String = "{\"message\": \"value\"}"
val b: String = "<tag>some</tag>"
```

And I need get from it its values in AnyContent format, not in JSON or XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `play.api.mvc.AnyContentAsText` for your purpose